# mySQL Select between 1000A and 2000A

Tags: mysql

In our database where are numbered pieces like this:

```
100
100A
110
110A
110B
300
400
505
505A
1000
1050
1050A
1050B
2500A
2600
3000
3000A
3050
```

How would I select a range when some have a letter at the end but I only want to select using the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where col * 1 between 1000 and 2000
```

`col * 1` transforms your column into a number to make the multiplication with 1. MySQL starts the conversion from left to right until no more numbers are found.

So `1010B` gets transformed to `1010`.

Another possibility would be

```
where cast(col as unsigned) between 1000 and 2000
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/53092)